# First Click Hiding, Second click showing again

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have two buttons. first button's id is `#doNotShowWhenClickedDetail` and second button's id is hidethisbutton.

When I click the first button, I want to hide the second button. When I click the first button again, I wanna show the second button this time.(Like clicking dropdown list).

Here is my jquery code. I have done the first click but could not manage the second click

```
$("#doNotShowWhenClickedDetail").click(

        function (){$("#hidethisbutton").hide();} 

 );
```

Thanks

Comment: use `toggle()` instead of `hide()`

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/toggle

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$("#doNotShowWhenClickedDetail").click(

  function() {
    $("#hidethisbutton").toggle();
  }

);
```

Comment: `hide()` is to hide an element. `show()` is to show an element. If you want to hide and show, use `toggle()`. That is what I did.
Consider Marking as answer

Answer (score 1):

you can add `toggle function`

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $("#doNotShowWhenClickedDetail").click(

        function ()
    {
        $("#hidethisbutton").toggle();
     } 

     );
});
```